# copyToRealmOrUpdate not working

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

I would like to update an realm object, but I haven't had success. I tried different ways, but I'm still getting the same exception.

[image: Exception]

First, I create a plant and then I search it in order to be updated. This works. But, when I try to update the plant with its new name, I received the exception related to the primary key constraint. So, is it supposed that the method copyToRealmOrUpdate will be used the key for search the object?

```
private void updatePlantRealm() {

    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name("garden.realm")
            .build();

    PlantRealmRepository repository = new PlantRealmRepository(config);

    Plant plant = new Plant();
    plant.setId("234");
    plant.setName("test");
    plant.setSize(30);
    plant.setGardenId("1452345");

    repository.add(plant);

    PlantByIdSpecification spec = new PlantByIdSpecification(plant.getId());

    repository.query(spec).subscribe(plants -> {
                Plant p = plants.get(0);
                p.setName("name");
                repository.update(p);
            }
    );

    spec = new PlantByIdSpecification(plant.getId());

    repository.query(spec).subscribe(plants -> {
                Plant p = plants.get(0);
                Assert.assertEquals(p.getName(), "name");
            }
    );
}
```

Update method. ToPlantRealm is a mapper, which transforms plant into plantRealm.

```
@Override
public void update(Plant plant) {

    final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
    realm.executeTransaction(realmParam -> realmParam.copyToRealmOrUpdate(toPlantRealm.map(plant)));
    realm.close();
    deleteDB(realm);
}
```

ADD Method

```
@Override
public void add(final Iterable<Plant> plants) {

    realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);

    realm.executeTransaction( realmParam -> {
        for (Plant plant : plants) {
            realmParam.copyToRealm(toPlantRealm.map(plant));
        }
    });

    realm.close();
}
```

The error is produced in this line

```
realm.executeTransaction(realmParam -> realmParam.copyToRealmOrUpdate(toPlantRealm.map(plant)));
```

I debugged inside Realm library and it says that the key already exists.

**UPDATED**

[image: Update Realm Failed]

Comment: @Christian Melchior Any idea about this?

Comment: The stack trace and the the code you posted doesn't seem to match, so it is hard to tell what is going on, e.g. what does `repository.add(plant)`  do?

Comment: @Christian Melchior I would like to know why the copyToRealmOrUpdate method decides that my object is new instead of old. That's way, the exception about the constraint is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` method is wrong. You should use `copyToRealmOrUpdate` instead of `copyToRealm`

```
@Override
public void add(final Iterable<Plant> plants) {

    realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);

    realm.executeTransaction( realmParam -> {
        for (Plant plant : plants) {
            realmParam.copyToRealmOrUpdate(toPlantRealm.map(plant));
        }
    });

    realm.close();
}
```